# Different Keymaps for Different Scopes

Tags: beamer, article, sublime-text, latextools

For the LaTeXTools package, used in Sublime text, how would you define the same shortcut to operate differently for two different `LaTeX` document classes?

E.g. suppose that you wanted to define "control+enter" in the keymap to operate in the following way for BEAMER:

```
// new equation line (LHS + RHS)
{ "keys": ["control+enter"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\n\\uncover<+->{$1} &   \\uncover<.->{=$2}  \\\\\\\\$0"}, 
"context":  
    [
        {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex string.other.math, text.tex.latex meta.environment.math"},
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```

But then have `"control+enter"` operate in the following way for ARTICLE

```
// new equation line (LHS + RHS)
{ "keys": ["control+enter"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\n$1    &   =$2 \\\\\\\\$0"}, 
"context":  
    [
        {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex string.other.math, text.tex.latex meta.environment.math"},
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```

That is, have `"control+enter"` wrap an align environment with uncover overlays for beamer, but not for the article document class.

How would you do it?

What would you need to define the `"operand"` (or scope) as in each case?

Comment: You can always see the current scope with `ctrl+alt+shift+p`. Unfortunatly the scopes do not depend on the documentclass, so you can define a different scope for math, but not for beamer. However it is possible to write your own context, which checks for the document type.

Comment: How would you go about writing your own context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the built-in scopes, but need a context. I will add the next [prerelease](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools#prereleases) (which is `st3-4.0.0-alpha.3`) via [LaTeXTools#1167](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/pull/1167).
If you have that prerelease you can just add the keybindings:

```js
{ 
    "keys": ["ctrl+enter"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\n$1    &   =$2 \\\\\\\\$0"}, 
    "context":  
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operand": "text.tex.latex meta.environment.math" },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true }
    ]
},
{ 
    "keys": ["ctrl+enter"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\n\\uncover<+->{$1} &   \\uncover<.->{=$2}  \\\\\\\\$0"}, 
    "context":  
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operand": "text.tex.latex meta.environment.math" },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "latextools.documentclass", "operand": "beamer" }
    ]
},
```

Until the release is published you can manually install it by

1. Download the file [here](https://github.com/r-stein/LaTeXTools/blob/context_provider/context_provider.py)
2. Open the LaTeXTools folder: in the Menu select *Preferences > Browse Packages...* and then open the LaTeXTools folder
3. Put the downloaded file there

To emulate a snippet install "Chain Of Command" and create this keybinding:

```js
{
    "keys": ["tab"],
    "command": "chain",
    "args": {"commands": [
        ["delete_word", {"forward": false}],
        ["insert_snippet", {"contents": "\\mybox<..>"}],
    ]},
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operand": false },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\bbox$", "match_all": true },  // <- change "box" here
        { "key": "selector", "operand": "text.tex.latex meta.environment.math" },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "latextools.documentclass", "operand": "beamer" },
    ]
},
```

Comment: Wow that is fantastic. Great work, thank you very much.

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar with a snippet?

Comment: No, you can't add your own contexts to keybindings. However you may emulate a snippet with a keybinding.

Comment: How would you code the keybinding? E.g. say I wanted to convert 'box' and then hit tab and form an emulated snippet through a keybinding, how would I do that?

Comment: @Pravin I have added a keybinding for that in the answer.