# Context Defined Snippets

Tags: sublime-text, scoping, latextools

[r-stein](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376826/different-keymaps-for-different-scopes) explained how you could define a keybinding in terms of a context specific to the document class (e.g. beamer or article). How could you do the same for a snippet?

MWE:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
\alert{$1} $0
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>test</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>latextools.documentclass.article</scope>
</snippet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write arbitrary contexts for snippets, but only scopes. Therefore you can't create a snippet for that. However you can emulate the snippet behavior by creating a keybinding for the `tab` key, which is only trigger if the text before the caret is `test`. This keybinding should remove the word before it and insert the snippet. If you install the "Chain Of Command" package you can just use this keybinding:

```js
{
    "keys": ["tab"],
    "command": "chain",
    "args": {"commands": [
        ["delete_word", {"forward": false}],
        ["insert_snippet", {"contents": "\\alert{$1} "}],
    ]},
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operand": "text.tex.latex" },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\btest$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "latextools.documentclass", "operand": "article" },
    ]
},
```

You can adapt it by changing the regex `"operand": "\\btest$",` to `"operand": "\\byour_trigger$",`

Comment: That's perfect. Sorry for the duplication, saw your answer to my comment on the other question as well.